# Basis of M2,2 is not spanning set of trace zero matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, span

given set of matrices:

S={[1 0; 0 0];[0 1; 0 0];[0 0; 1 0];[0 0; 0 1]}

I have to explain why S is not a spanning set of matrices with trace zero, matrices of:

V be the subspace of M2,2: V = {[a b; c d] |a+d=0,a,b,c,d∈R}

however according to my assumptions:
a[1 0; 0 0]+b[0 1; 0 0]+c[0 0; 1 0]-a[0 0; 0 1] ∈ V.

I'm getting the combination of S spanning V.
Are my calculations wrong or something, please advice.

Comment: Does every matrix in the span of $S$ have trace 0?

Comment: $S$ is a spanning set for all of $M_{2,2}(\mathbb R)$, in particular it spans any subset of  $M_{2,2}(\mathbb R)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S$ is said to be a spanning set of $V$ if its linear span is **exactly** equal to $V$. Your $S$ spans the whole space $M_{2,2}$, which is strictly larger than $V$. So, $S$ not a spanning set of $V$.

Comment: in other words rank of V is 3 and rank of S is 4, that's why V can't span S, right?

Comment: @MotherLand By "rank", do you mean dimension? Also, the question is whether $S$ is a spanning set of $V$, not the other way round.

Comment: my bad, dimension that is :) yes, whether S is a spanning set of V.

Comment: @MotherLand Then yes, the span of $S$ is $M_{2,2}$, whose dimension is 4, which is greater than the dimension of $V$, which is 3. If $S$ is a spanning of $V$, then at least its span should have the same dimension as $V$, but in fact it spans more than $V$.